# JavaScript: Convert array of objects into hashmap in Generic

Tags: javascript

I have a set of values in an array where each value has an ID and LABEL.

```
const data = [
{ID: 0, LABEL: 'turbo'},
{ID: 1, LABEL: 'classic'},
{ID: 7, LABEL: 'unknown'}
];

const hashMap = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  return { ...result, [ item.ID ] : item.LABEL };
}, {});

const hashMapJson = JSON.stringify(hashMap);

console.log('hashMap', hashMap);
console.log('hashMapJson', hashMapJson);
```

But if I have the following json object where key is slightly different, it does not handle of course. I wonder how I could able to make the above solution in more generic to tackle different inputs.

```
const data = [
{K_ID: 0, K_LABEL: 'turbo'},
{L_ID: 1, K_LABEL: 'classic'},
{S_ID: 7, K_LABEL: 'unknown'}
];
```

Comment: do you have same pattern with `ID` and `LABEL`? please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: I have similar pattern, `ANYTHING_ID` and `ANYTHING_LABEL`

Comment: You could use Array#map to change all your objects to the first form: `const normalizedData = data.map( obj => ({ [obj[Object.keys( obj ).find( key => /_ID$/.test(key) )]]: obj[Object.keys( obj ).find( key => /_LABEL$/.test(key) )] }) );`, then convert it to a map the same way you already do: `const hashMap = nomalizedData.reduce( ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your hashMap function to something like the following :

```js
const data = [{K_ID: 0, K_LABEL: 'turbo'},{L_ID: 1, K_LABEL: 'classic'},{S_ID: 7, K_LABEL: 'unknown'}];

const hashMap = data.reduce((result, item) => {
    let id
    let label

    Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
        if (key.includes('ID')) {
            id = key
        } else if (key.includes('LABEL')) {
            label = key
        }
    })

    return { ...result, [ item[id] ] : item[label] };
}, {});

console.log( hashMap );
```

This is assuming your data set you are passing (`data`) is similar the the one in the example you provided.  As long as a key contains ID, it'll make that the id key and as long as a key contains LABEL it will make that the key for the LABEL

Comment: I think this is the best answer, but you might want to include the underscore in your searches to handle some weird cases like `{LABEL_ID: 121, LABEL_LABEL: 'label'}`

Answer (score 2):

You can try following using [String.endsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

```js
const data = [{K_ID: 0, K_LABEL: 'turbo'},{L_ID: 1, K_LABEL: 'classic'},{S_ID: 7, K_LABEL: 'unknown'}];

const hashMap = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  const temp = Object.keys(item);
  const key = temp[0].endsWith("_ID") ? 0 : 1; // check for 1st key ending with _ID
  const value = +!key; // if key is 1, value be 0 and other way around
  result[item[temp[key]]] = item[temp[value]];
  return result;
}, {});

const hashMapJson = JSON.stringify(hashMap);
console.log(hashMapJson);
```

Comment: This assumes the objects all only have two keys (probably a valid assumption).

Comment: @Paulpro - `temp[0].indexOf("_ID") === temp[0].length - 3` will work for `AA_ID` as well

Comment: @Paulpro - I have though updated to `endsWith` which is what I wanted to achieve with indexOf and length

Comment: why are you using "_ID"? it won't work on the OP's base example unless its "ID"

Comment: In the comments OP has clarified the pattern will be SOMETHING_ID.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends of your data model, but this should work...

```js
const data = [
{K_ID: 0, K_LABEL: 'turbo'},
{L_ID: 1, K_LABEL: 'classic'},
{S_ID: 7, K_LABEL: 'unknown'}
]

const hashMap = data.reduce((ac, cv) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(cv)
  let id, label
  keys.forEach(key => {
 if(key.endsWith('_LABEL'))
  label = cv[key]
 else if(key.endsWith('_ID'))
  id = cv[key]
  })
  
  if(id !== undefined && label !== undefined)
 ac[id] = label
  
  return ac
}, {})

console.log(hashMap)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a function for finding a similar key of the object.

```js
const 
    getSimilarKey = (object, key) => Object.keys(object).find(k => k.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase())),
    data = [{ K_ID: 0, K_LABEL: 'turbo' }, { L_ID: 1, K_LABEL: 'classic' }, { S_ID: 7, K_LABEL: 'unknown' }],
    key = 'id', 
    value = 'label',
    result = Object.assign(
        {},
        ...data.map(o => ({ [o[getSimilarKey(o, key)]]: o[getSimilarKey(o, value)] }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With upcoming `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const 
    getSimilarKey = (object, key) => Object.keys(object).find(k => k.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase())),
    data = [{ K_ID: 0, K_LABEL: 'turbo' }, { L_ID: 1, K_LABEL: 'classic' }, { S_ID: 7, K_LABEL: 'unknown' }],
    key = 'id', 
    value = 'label',
    result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(o => ({ [o[getSimilarKey(o, key)]]: o[getSimilarKey(o, value)] })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make create an `extractIdLabel` function that tries to guess the keys for ID and Label respectively. You can use regex (via `string.prototype.match`) or other tools to make it as robust as required.

In the example below,

1) it looks for the keys 'id' and 'label'. e.g. `{id: 0, label: 'zero'}`

2) If one or both are not found, then it looks for keys containing the strings 'id' and 'label'. e.g. `{x_id: 0, y_label_z: 'zero'}`

3) If still one of them is not found, but the other is found, and the item has 2 keys, it uses the unused key for the not-found one. e.g. `{id: 0, obviously_not_id_so_must_be_L_a_b_e_l: 'zero'}`

```js
const data = [
  {K_ID: -1, K_LABEL: 'turbo'},
  {L_ID: 1, K_LABEL: 'classic'},
  {S_ID: 7, K_LABEL: 'unknown'},
  {ID: 10, LABEL: 'ten', garbage: 'garbage', bad_label: 'bad_label'},
  {KEY: 11, X_LABEL: 'eleven'},
  {Y_ID: 12, VALUE: 'twelve'},
  {id: 0, obviously_not_id_so_must_be_L_a_b_e_l: 'zero'}
];

let extractIdLabel = item => {
  let keys = Object.keys(item);
  let id = keys.find(key => key.toLowerCase() === 'id') ||
      keys.find(key => key.toLowerCase().includes('id'));
  let label = keys.find(key => key.toLowerCase() === 'label') ||
      keys.find(key => key.toLowerCase().includes('label'));
  if (keys.length === 2 && !id ^ !label)
    if (!id)
      id = keys.find(key => key !== label);
    else
      label = keys.find(key => key !== id);
  return [item[id], item[label]];
};

const hashMap = data.reduce((result, item) => {
  let [id, label] = extractIdLabel(item);
  return {...result, [id]: label};
}, {});

const hashMapJson = JSON.stringify(hashMap);

console.log('hashMap', hashMap);
console.log('hashMapJson', hashMapJson);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you used an XOR operator, but no matter what operator you use `!id` is not useful, because it gives the same value for `id === 0` as it does for no `id` being found.

Comment: I think you can just do something like this: `if ( id !== undefined && label === undefined && keys.length === 2 ) label = keys.find(key => key !== id); if ( label !== undefined && id === undefined && keys.length === 2 ) id = keys.find(key => key !== label);`

Comment: `!id ^ !label` is a succinct way of checking if one of them was found, and the other is still undefined. Your suggestion isn't wrong, but it's like a paragraph when a few words would have done just fine.

Comment: I disagree, my suggestion is less lines, less nesting, and clearer code IMO. Your code is the equivalent of "if exactly one of these is set, then if the first one is not set, do X, otherwise do Y" which has an extra condition and is harder to understand than necessary (which "if" is the "otherwise" applying to?) Mine is "if the first one is not set and the second one is, do X. if the second one is set and the first one is not, do Y." and, in my opinion, it is much clearer what is happening in the latter. Also, my code works.

Comment: You could make yours work too with something like `id === undefined ^ label === undefined` and also changing the next if statement to `if ( id === undefined )`

Comment: I would remove my downvote if your code could handle the `{id: 0, obviously_not_id_so_must_be_L_a_b_e_l: 'zero'}` case that you claim it does. To do that you need to treat id's of `0` differently and also make your search case-insensitive (or change your example to `{ID: 0, ...`

Comment: Good catch regarding case sensitivity, fixed. Re, `obviously_not_id_so_must_be_L_a_b_e_l` it works fine, as I've added it to the example, I'm not sure why you think it needs differentiating undefined from other falsley values, keys can't be falsey as they're (non-empty) strings.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought you were testing whether the value was found not the key. The variable name `id` threw me off, since it doesn't actually hold the `id`.